# cglib: Java dynamic proxy for class without constructor (HttpUrlConnection)

Tags: java, proxy, cglib

I'm unable to create dynamic proxy for HttpURLConnection class, since it don't have public constructor to create Enhancer. Coming to requirement, I want to create a dynamic proxy to get details of current connection at run time.

I tried using [this](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/wiki/How-To) tutorial, but failed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library like [*Objenesis*](http://objenesis.org/) to create instances of classes that do not offer a suitable constructor. You can use cglib for creating the subclass but without creating the instance in this case.